# How do you put a variable date on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I've been trying to use the input data from my HTML to create a date object but no mater what I tweak, it either shows invalid date, or gives today's date.
Any help on how I can solve this? Or corrections on what I may be doing wrong?
Thanks.
Here's my code below.

```
    <input type="date" id="date">
    <script>
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value();
    var d = new Date(d);
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? set the date of the input to a desired date?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of value that is in the `date` input?

Comment: Also this appears to be a typo: `var d = new Date(d);`.  Do you mean `new Date(date);`?

Comment: you have `var d = new Date(d);` - surely you mean `var d = new Date(date);`

Comment: @John Yes, I want to set the date on js to whatever the user inputs on the webpage.

Comment: @Martin the date. any date.

Comment: @Craicerjack I want the date to be equal to whatever is inputted in variable d. Is that the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be helpful to you:

```js
        function x(){
        var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
        var d = new Date(date);
        console.log(d);
        }
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
<button onclick="x()">show</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You put wrong .value() change to .value.

You can use momentjs to format date YYYY-MM-DD

```
function check(){
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var d = new moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(d)
}
```

```js
function check(){
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var d = new moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(d)
}
```

```html
    <input type="date" id="date" onblur="check()">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Why mention moment? It's not needed here, is it? Just use `Date.parse()`, If the user has very specific needs, then they may need a library, but the question doesn't seem to be asking about that

Comment: It is one suggestion, in real project I often use momentjs for handle date format

Comment: I'm extremely new to coding (approximately a week old) but the snippet worked. Thanks for answering! I'll come back to that answer when I advance slightly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Date experiment</title>

<script>
function processDate(mdate){
    console.log(mdate); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<form>
  Date : <br>
  <input type="date" id="start" name="mydate" onchange="processDate(this.value)"
       value="2019-10-20" min="2019-10-01" max="2019-12-31">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't started working with forms yet but i will refer to this in future.